# How to find link between /dev/video and lsusb output

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, video

Linux exposes camera interfaces at `/dev/video*` but that interface doesn't describe the make/model of the camera. Meanwhile, `lsusb` reports the make/model of all USB devices, including the cameras, but it doesn't tell you which `/dev` file they correspond to. How do I link a device reported by `lsusb` to a `/dev/video*` file?

Comment: Have you considered `hwinfo` for such? It corresponds the identified device to its file location (/dev/xyz) which you seek here.

Comment: @Firelord, That does look very helpful. Specifically it tells me the sysfs path which contains a link to the video4linux/videoN path. However, I'm not sure how portable `hwinfo` is. I need something that will work across embedded systems.

Answer (score 3):

Checking `/sys/class/video4linux/video$N/name` and `/sys/class/video4linux/video$N/device/driver/*` will give give you data, that you will let you find the `lsusb` line.